# Win 7 doesn't have SMTP Server

Tags: smtp

Currently, i am  working on sending/receiving mail project on Win7, i want to use Seolib.dll (COM) to handle for event sending/receiving mails but Win7 is not supported this one. So is there any solution for this issue?

I am doing on C# language.

using SEOLib;

namespace CatGlobeSmtpEventSink_Head 
{ 
   public class CatGlobeMailTransportSubmission : ISMTPOnArrival, IEventIsCacheable 
   { 
      private static List siteInfos; 
      private static CGDateTime lastRefresh = CGDateTime.MinValue;

```
  private static object locker = new object(); 

  public CatGlobeMailTransportSubmission() 
  { 
     Logger.CreateInstance(ConfigurationInfo.CreateInstance(), true).Add(LogEntryType.Information, "{0} constructor called", ConfigurationInfo.SINK_NAME); 
     RefreshConfiguration(); 
  }
```

.....................................

Comment: What programming language? What environment?? There's plenty of "for dev purposes only" SMTP Servers out there.....

Answer (score -1):

I am doing on C# language.

using SEOLib;

namespace CatGlobeSmtpEventSink_Head
{
   public class CatGlobeMailTransportSubmission : ISMTPOnArrival, IEventIsCacheable
   {
      private static List siteInfos;
      private static CGDateTime lastRefresh = CGDateTime.MinValue;

```
  private static object locker = new object();

      public CatGlobeMailTransportSubmission()
  {
     Logger.CreateInstance(ConfigurationInfo.CreateInstance(), true).Add(LogEntryType.Information, "{0} constructor called", ConfigurationInfo.SINK_NAME);
     RefreshConfiguration();
  }
  .....................................
```

...................................................

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. If you have more information about your problem, then please edit your original question - do not add an answer.